# Workaround for retrieving user's Youtube watch history

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I wrote a handy script to manage one of my Playlists by removing any watched videos from the list. Unfortunately with the revision to the API on September 15, 2016, the user's watch history is no longer available via the API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history)

Is there another way I can achieve this Playlist-cleaning functionality?

For example, if I can't get a user's entire watch history (which is overkill for my use case anyway) maybe there's a way to query whether a specific single video has been watched (or maybe even get the watched percentage or watched minutes for a video, like the red bar under the video thumbnail shows)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no workaround in getting the watch history of a user. You can check the [API v3 - Watch History](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642) issue tracker and [Revision History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) for more information about it.

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Nope. And I'm writing an app that could really use that feature. It used to be there but not anymore. Maybe if you use v2 of the API, but I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

I think there is still one workground. 
You can read the HTML content of https://www.youtube.com/feed/history
But I don't think this way is a good way.