# No longer able to get watched history of youtube user using Youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

All the related SO questions and answers say to use the playlist ID returned in the `contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory` returned by the `youtube.channels.list` endpoint. That value now always seems to be set to `"HL"`. I'm using an OAuth token to authenticate the request. Is there another way to get the list of recently watched videoes for the authenticated user? I also noticed that the list of watched videos no longer appears on the user's YouTube home page, just recommended videoes. Am I just SOL or is there some new way to access the watch history?

Comment: AFAIK, `watchHistory` is now deprecated for YouTube API. You can also check my comment in a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478952/workaround-for-retrieving-users-youtube-watch-history#comment70221611_41478952) which includes the issue tracker link and revision page for additional information

Comment: Thanks, that's the conclusion I had come to. The issue tracker page was amusing to read through. It seems odd that they would change the TOS to ban screen scraping and then deprecate the API, thus leaving screen scraping as the only way to get the data. 

Oh well, I just removed YouTube integration from my app. Their loss I guess.