# Using Youtube API 3 in Javascript to get user's watched history

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am using Google's Youtube API V3 and trying to get user's watched video history, I can get his activity, liked videos but still can't figure out how to check only watched videos.

note: I tried to get his channel and get videos of watched history playlist but it always returns "HL" with empty array like this:

```
"contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
      "likes": "LLF7yph1rnu6gZ-7ctZZwBAw",
      "favorites": "FLF7yph1rnu6gZ-7ctZZwBAw",
      "uploads": "UUF7yph1rnu6gZ-7ctZZwBAw",
      "watchHistory": "HL",
      "watchLater": "WL"
    }
  },
```

, so you might think of another procedure.

Comment: Can't mark as dupe, but dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478952/workaround-for-retrieving-users-youtube-watch-history

Comment: It isn't solved though, Thank you Isaac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround for retrieving user's Youtube watch history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478952/workaround-for-retrieving-users-youtube-watch-history)